# Apply styling to angular toast from within a component method

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I need to apply a styling to a toast that will be used when a particular function is called. How do I do that?

toast.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class ToastrService {

    public toasterStatus: BehaviorSubject<Message>;

    constructor() {
        this.toasterStatus = new BehaviorSubject<Message>(null);
    }
    showToaster(type: string, content: string) {
        const toasterObj: Message = { severity: type, detail: content };
        this.toasterStatus.next(toasterObj);
    }
}

export interface Message {
    severity: String;
    detail: String;
}
```

my-component.ts

```
import { ToastrService } from '../../../toast.service';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
constructor(private logService: LogService,
    private toastrService: ToastrService,){...}

ngOnInit() {

    this.idSubscription$ = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params['id'];
    });
    this.logService.debug(this.id);


      // check for error
      if (my.error) {
        this.logService.error('Error retrieving report templates.', reportTemplatesState);
        this.toastrService.showToaster('danger', 'Error retrieving report templates.'); 
  }
});
```

**//I need to apply the styling below to this toastrService element within the component method**

my.component.css

```
.toastSticky{ 
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this with the **[documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarConfig)** :

```
MatSnackBarConfig
Configuration used when opening a snack-bar.

    panelClass: string | string[]                    Extra CSS classes to be 
                                                     added to the snack bar container.
```

Comment: thanks @trichetriche. I have added the following line to my ToastrService: ToastrServiceConfig: { panelClass: 'toastSticky' } but did not have any affect.

Comment: Because the styles in the components are encapsulated (unless you state otherwise). Put the style into your `style.css` file to make it global.